# Why does not work my avfoundation swift3

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

When you run the following project, edited video will be generated on the device. I tried the following implementation with audio file and succeeded. However, if you run it as a movie, no error will be issued but a movie will be generated and will not go into the directory
https://github.com/Ryosuke-Hujisawa/My_AVAssetExportSession_AVMutableComposition-2

There is a model in my project. The model is below
https://github.com/justinlevi/AVAssetExportSession_AVMutableComposition

I succeeded in audio file. Audio was in the directory in trimmed and edited state. I want to edit the video. Although I could edit the video, it is edited and no error occurs, but the result does not exist in the directory. Or it exists in the directory in the state of the audio file and it is not generated as animation. Please help me.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var asset: AVAsset?

  @IBAction func exportBtnDidTap(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    guard let asset = asset else {
      return
    }

    createAudioFileFromAsset(asset)
  }


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "m4v")!)

    let comp = AVMutableComposition()

    let videoAssetSourceTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first! as AVAssetTrack


    let videoCompositionTrack = comp.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    do {

        try videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(
            CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10, 600)),
            of: videoAssetSourceTrack,
            at: kCMTimeZero)

    }catch { print(error) }

    asset = comp
  }

  func deleteFile(_ filePath:URL) {
    guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) else {
      return
    }

    do {
      try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: filePath.path)
    }catch{
      fatalError("Unable to delete file: \(error) : \(#function).")
    }
  }

  func createAudioFileFromAsset(_ asset: AVAsset){

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL

    let filePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("rendered-audio.m4v")
    deleteFile(filePath)

    if let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A){

      exportSession.canPerformMultiplePassesOverSourceMediaData = true
      exportSession.outputURL = filePath
      exportSession.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
      exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
      exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        _ in
        print("finished: \(filePath) :  \(exportSession.status.rawValue) ")
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: i try exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A -> exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4V

Comment: but this is err ->  reason: 'Invalid output file type'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Try AVFileTypeMPEG4?

Comment: and i try  -> if let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset640x480){

Comment: i success !!!!!!!!!!! exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4V ->  exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie ❤️

Answer (score 0):

I could crop the video with the implementation below. Also updated github

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var asset: AVAsset?

  @IBAction func exportBtnDidTap(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    guard let asset = asset else {
      return
    }

    createAudioFileFromAsset(asset)
  }


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "m4v")!)

    let comp = AVMutableComposition()

    let videoAssetSourceTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first! as AVAssetTrack


    let videoCompositionTrack = comp.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    do {

        try videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(
            CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 600)),
            of: videoAssetSourceTrack,
            at: kCMTimeZero)

    }catch { print(error) }

    asset = comp
  }

  func deleteFile(_ filePath:URL) {
    guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) else {
      return
    }

    do {
      try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: filePath.path)
    }catch{
      fatalError("Unable to delete file: \(error) : \(#function).")
    }
  }

  func createAudioFileFromAsset(_ asset: AVAsset){

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL

    let filePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("rendered-audio.m4v")
    deleteFile(filePath)

    if let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset640x480){

      exportSession.canPerformMultiplePassesOverSourceMediaData = true
      exportSession.outputURL = filePath
      exportSession.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
      exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
      exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        _ in
        print("finished: \(filePath) :  \(exportSession.status.rawValue) ")
      }
    }

  }
}
```